# How to display html as text in email

Tags: html, email, html-email

I'm trying to output example html code in an html email as plain text, but I can't figure out how to do it. I tried changing all > to `&gt;` and all < to `&lt;`. As well I tried using the `<pre></pre>` tag but that doesn't seem to work either. I've seen this done before. Any idea how to do this? Here's the original code:

```
<a href="http://www.schedulicity.com/Scheduling/Default.aspx?business={!Account_ExternalID}" title="Online scheduling" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.schedulicity.com/Business/Images/ScheduleNow_LG.png" alt="Schedule online now" border="0" /></a>
```

This is what the source looks like:

[image]

This is what the preview looks like:

[image]

This is what the final sent email looks like:

[image]

Comment: What are you using to generate the text, and what does the final message actually look like?

Comment: I'm coding it by hand. In the ESP the html is displayed, but when it's sent the final message outputs the html as html (in this case it displays a button).

Comment: The email client used for viewing the email is likely going to have a large impact on how you achieve this.

Comment: @KevinBoucher yes I did, please see the question. I'll give the code tag a try.

Comment: code tag doesn't work, but I'm now testing xmp tag

Comment: what does it look like when you convert > to `&gt;`? In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: I included images above so you can see. The result is the same regardless of whether I use the pre, code or xmp tags.

Comment: How do you turn the HTML markup into an email?

Comment: @JoshLee that's all done by the ESP. The only data I have is above. When I check the source in my email client (working in outlook at the moment), it looks exactly like the source in image #1

Answer (score 0):

Add `\r\n Content-type: text/plain;` in headers, or change existing.

If you want only a part of body not translated try putting it into `<xmp></xmp>`

Comment: Wouldn't that change the entire template to be a text template? I only want that specific portion to display as text.

Comment: you can always throw html in wysiwyg editor and copy it from code part.
but thats not permanent solution

Answer (score 0):

If u just want the html code to be shown as such, try putting the code inside a textarea and make the textarea disabled and hide its border.